# iOS Permission Alert not displaying when app is back to foreground from background

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an application whose first screen uses web auth session using SFAuthenticationSession

General Behaviour: As soon as my app launches, it prompts me with ios default Auth alert "My App xxx wants to use "testauthentication.com" to sign In" with options continue and cancel

This alert is default popup handled by iOS framework

Now My issue is: When the app launches and this alert is shown, if i lock and my screen and unlock it again - the pop up disappears and user is blocked and the only way to move ahead is kill and relaunch the app.

My question is how can i show the alert dialog again so user can continue

I thought of reloading view when app moves back and forth from background to foreground. But the pop up is appearing only once but not everytime. Not sure if this is right approach too. Please advice

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    AppHelper.sharedInstance.isAppLaunchedForFirstTime = false
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let isUserLoggedIn = AppHelper.sharedInstance.isUserLoggedIn ?? false     
    let appLaunchedForFirstTime = AppHelper.sharedInstance.isAppLaunchedForFirstTime ?? false
    if !appLaunchedForFirstTime && !isUserLoggedIn {
        if let viewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController as? LoginViewController {
            viewController.navigateToLogin(from: viewController)
        }
    }
}
```

So when locked applicationDidEnterBackground will be called and setting bool to false
When brought back again to foreground, applicationDidBecomeActive will be called and viewController.navigateToLogin(from: viewController) will execute. But this doesnt show pop up everytime

Another problem is method navigateToLogin(from: viewController) actually pushes new viewcontroller to stack. So Instead of reloading im creating duplicate which is worst practice. But how can i handle these scenarios. Please advice

Comment: Not sure if you are aware but `SFAuthenticationSession` is Deprecated in future releases and the replacement is `ASWebAuthenticationSession`.  What happens if you use `applicationWillEnterForeground` instead of `applicationDidBecomeActive`?